# Validar input con VUE

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

Tengo este input:

```
<b-input
            type="text"
            :value="googleTagManagerCode"
            :maxlength="12"
            placeholder="GTM-XXXXXX"
            @change="updatetagmanagercode"
          />
```

en data:

```
googleTagManagerCode: null
```

y en methods el post/get de la configuracion de google tag manager y los mensajes de error o validación al tocar el boton "guardar":

```
async confirm () {
      helperModal.showWindowContentLoading()
      let response = await ApiService.post('/config/updateExtraConfiguration', {
        google_tag_manager_code: this.googleTagManagerCode
      });

      if (response.success) {
        this.messageManager.showSuccessMessage(this.translateText('Se han guardado correctamente los cambios.'))
        helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
      } else {
        this.messageManager.showErrorMessage(this.translateText('No se han podido guardar los cambios. Intenta nuevamente.'))
        helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
      }
    },
    updatetagmanagercode (value) {
      this.googleTagManagerCode = value
    },
    async loadGoogleTagManagerCode () {
      let response = await ApiService.get('/config/company/google_tag_manager_code', {
        google_tag_manager_code: this.googleTagManagerCode
      });
      if (!response.success) {
        this.messageManager.showErrorMessage(this.translateText(response.message))
      } else {
        helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
      }
      return response
    }
  },
  created () {
     this.loadGoogleTagManagerCode()
  },
```

Pero necesito validar que el formato de entrada ingresado por el usuario en el input empiece al menos con "GTM-" para que no me guarde cualquier cosa que ingresen (actualmente ingresando cualquier texto lo guarda)

como se realiza esto en vue?

probe con aria-required pero no funcionó.

Comment: Que tal si al b-input le agregas estos 2 atributos pattern="^GMT-" title="Enter a valid date"

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas es una muy buena opcion pero sigue sin funcionar. me sigue dejando ingresar cualquier tipo de dato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más sencillo para hacer es usar vee-validate, un framework para validación, y ya te queda para otras partes de tu proyecto.

https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/custom-rules.html#creating-a-custom-rule

Espero que te sirva,

Saludos.